# Is vmlinux a virtual machine?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux),

> On Linux systems, vmlinux is a statically linked executable file that contains the Linux kernel

Does that mean vmlinux is a virtual machine that runs Linux? I am really confused.

Comment: Provide a definition of *virtual machine*. An operating system (kernel(?)) turn shardware with idiosyncrasies into a virtual machine with a specification (ideally: and behaviour) identical over diverse hardware: *vmlinux* turns a Raspberry into a linux machine. Or some Apple. Or [a linux machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux).

Answer (score 1):

`vmlinux` is the executable file that is generated when building the Linux kernel. This isn't a normal executable file that would be generated as a result of compiling a program using, say, gcc.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) suggests, this executable needs to be further processed to be made bootable, but this is the essentially the executable image of the kernel.

> Does that mean vmlinux is a virtual machine that runs Linux?

No, the 'vm' here stands for 'virtual memory'. From Wikipedia,

> With the development of virtual memory, kernels that supported this feature were given the vm- prefix to differentiate them. The name vmlinux is a mutation of vmunix.

What is this `vmlinux` executable good for? Well, for starters, it can be made bootable and then booted on a physical computer.

You can also use this executable to run a virtual machine using qemu. Then, you can debug the kernel that is running in the virtual machine using gdb.